# Resolve Elasticsearch date expressions to timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch

I have a task to somehow check before querying ES that user provided a correct timestamps for time range. Specifically I need to resolve expressions like "*now*", "*now-1d*", "*now+1h*" to valid timestamp. Any idea how I can do it without doing hardcore stuff like trying on my own to parse strings to date format?
In other words I need to convert "*now-1h*" to something like *date(2023, 10, 07,x,x,x)* or any other valid format.
Maybe I can somehow check it with ES first by sending some simple query?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can validate your entire query using [validate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) command. So you can craft a small date range query and put a timestamp there.

Saying this I think you will be just wasting time. If dates are incorrect you will get a very quick response from elasticsearch, which you can then send back to the user. You also don't need to do anything to resolve expressions like "now", "now-1d", "now+1h" before sending them to elasticsearch. Elasticsearch supports [these and a fews other expression](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) when it expects a timestamp.